# Print Version of a page. I want to append full url of relative links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a CSS file when the media type = print that will append the link address to the content for each link.  There is not a problem with absolute links to external pages but is problematic with relative links to other pages on my site  **which are not always at the same folder level of the link.**

So far:

I have identified the links that I wish to display:

```
$(".TreasuryLink").each(function(i) { 
var thisLink = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Once again my problem is retrieving the full url where the link may go to a different level in the sites file structure like

```
<a href="../../anotherpage.html">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always define this in your CSS style sheet. Try out the following line of style:

```
@media print{
  a:after{content:" (" attr(href) ")"}
}
```

This will add whatever the `href` value of the link is directly after the link in parenthesis. You could theoretically add the rest of the path on that rule, so it would look something like this:

```
@media print{
  a:after{content:" (http://www.domain.com/" attr(href) ")"}
}
```

However, this will affect **all** hyperlinks the same way (unless you select certain `a` elements differently using CSS). Meaning, if you have a mixture of full links *and* partial links, you'll have to make some different classes or select those `a` tags differently.

From you sample code, you could do it like this:

```
@media print{
  a.TreasuryLink:after{content:" (http://www.domain.com/" attr(href) ")"}
}
```

But, this also won't work if you use paths like `../../file.html`. You would need to change those URLs to be something like `/path/to/file.html`, which in my opinion would be better anyways.

The end result will make it look like this on the printed version of the page:

> Click here to contact us!
>   (http://www.domain.com/contact.html)

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I was looking to do but learning about the :after capabilities in CSS is awesome and makes it worth adding the separate classes for external content. <br /> Is there a way I could add the :after code to existing css declarations for the TreasuryLink class?

Comment: What I meant was where would I place he the code in a section like this:    a.TreasuryLink, a.TreasuryLinkExt {
 display:inline;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-weight: normal;
}

Answer (score 4):

You could narrow it down to relative links like this:

a[href^="/"]:after {
    content: " (http://www.example.com" attr(href) ") " !important;}

I know I wouldn't have the time to go back through my code and find ALL the relative links to add classes to!

Comment: remember to add four spaces before code samples to make code more readable.

Comment: Thanks saved me quite a bit of time with this dirty but working fix.